# Display button value in div onclick. Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a set of buttons with different values. When I press a button I want the value of the button to be displayed in the div `picked_letters`, but nothing is showing. The code is divided in an html file and a javascript file.

html file looks like this:

```
<body>

<script src="cases.js"></script>

<div id="written_word">
</div>

<div id="list_of_letters">
</div>

<div id="picked_letters">

</div>

</body>
```

and the onclick in the javascript file looks like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.style.background = 'silver';
    btn.style.width = '15%';
    btn.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    btn.style.fontSize = '135%';
    btn.style.display = 'inline-block';
    btn.value = case_values[i];
    btn.onmouseover = function (){
        btn.style.background = 'goldenrod';
    }
    btn.onmouseleave = function() {
        btn.style.background = 'silver';
    }
    btn.onclick = function() {
        btn.style.background = 'darkgrey';
        btn.disabled = true;
        btn.innerHTML = String(btn.value);
        document.getElementById("picked_letters").innerHTML =
            String(btn.value);
    }
    btn.innerHTML = String(i+1);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

The button changes color, becomes disabled and displays the value inside the button but it's the last line with getting the button value into a div that I am having problems with. Have looked around but haven't found a solution that solves this problem.

##Edit: The problem seems to have been fixed when I put the script import at the end of the body (and some other minor changes).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting the value of the button?
Can you share the button code?

Does your button look like this?

```
<button>My Button</button>
```

or do you set your value like this?

```
<button value="my button value">My button</button>
```

If you have a value set - you can do this:

```
btn.onclick = function () {
  console.log(btn.innerHTML);
  btn.style.background = "darkgrey";
  btn.disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("picked_letters").innerHTML = btn.value;
};
```

If you don't have a value set - using btn.value won't return anything.
I would try adding a value to your button if you dont have one. Or if you want to call the innerhtml of the button:

```
<button>My button</button>
```

and then

```
btn.onclick = function () {
  console.log(btn.innerHTML);
  btn.style.background = "darkgrey";
  btn.disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("picked_letters").innerHTML = btn.innerHTML;
};
```

Comment: I edited my question with my entire create-button-loop in the javascript file. I set a value to the button before the onclick, it is a random letter from the alphabet, se line ```btn.value = case_values[i]```. And I believe a value is set because the button text changes to the button value in the onclick-part.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is perfectly fine, the is definately being displayed in the "picked_letters" div, but the value of btn is ""(empty) so the value set to the div is also empty. To solve this issue, add value to the button by doing:-
. and the issue will be gone.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
btn.onclick = function() {
  btn.style.background = 'darkgrey';
  btn.disabled = true;
  console.log(btn.value)
  btn.innerHTML = String(btn.value);
  document.getElementById("picked_letters").innerHTML = 
    String(btn.value);
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="written_word">
  
</div>

<div id="list_of_letters">
</div>

<div id="picked_letters">

</div>
  <button id='btn' value='5'>Tap me</button>

</body>
```

Comment: I edited my question with my entire create-button-loop in the javascript file. I set a value to the button before the onclick, it is a random letter from the alphabet, se line ```btn.value = case_values[i]```. And I believe a value is set because the button text changes to the button value in the onclick-part.